# Extjs - How to refer the json datas in a controller?

Tags: json, extjs, extjs4, store

I'm developing a simple login page wherein I need to compare the value that has been entered by any user in username field, with the json data store on click of 'LoginButton'. My question is, can we get the list of username from the json store in an array and compare with textfield values? If so, how?

My nSpaceIndex.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>nSpace | Expense / Project Solutions</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
Ext.application({
    requires: ['Ext.container.Viewport'],
    name: 'nSpace',
    controllers: [
        'nSpaceController'
    ],
    appFolder: 'app',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            items: {
                xtype: 'loginView'
            }
        });
    }
});
```

my nSpaceController.js:

```
Ext.define('nSpace.controller.nSpaceController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores: [
        'Users'
    ],
    views: [
        'login.loginView'
    ],
    model: 'loginModel',
    init: function() {
        this.control({
            "#loginButton": {
                click: this.onLoginButtonClick
            }
        });
    },
    onLoginButtonClick: function(){
                //var jsonArray = store.Users.data.items
                //console.log(jsonArray);
                            // I NEED TO GET THE REFERENCE OF MY STORE: USERS TO COMPARE
                            var logUserName = Ext.getCmp('getUserName').getValue();
                var logPassword = Ext.getCmp('getPassword').getValue();             
                if(logUserName == 'user01' && logPassword == 'password01'){
                    Ext.MessageBox.show({title: 'Success', msg: 'You will be redirected to the home page in few moments...', icon:Ext.MessageBox.INFO});
                }
                else if(logUserName == 'user02' && logPassword == 'password02'){
                    Ext.MessageBox.show({title: 'Success', msg: 'You will be redirected to the home page in few moments...', icon:Ext.MessageBox.INFO});
                }
                else{
                    Ext.MessageBox.show({title: 'OOPS!!!', msg: 'Please Enter Valid Details', icon:Ext.MessageBox.WARNING});
                }
    },

});
```

my loginModel.js:

```
Ext.define('nSpace.model.loginModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['loginusername', 'password']
});
```

Users.js:

```
Ext.define('nSpace.store.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'nSpace.model.loginModel',

    autoLoad : true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data/users.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users',
            successProperty: 'success'
        }
    }
});
```

loginView.js:

```
Ext.define('nSpace.view.login.loginView' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.loginView',
    store: 'Users',
    title: 'nSpace | Login',
    frame:true,
    bodyPadding: 5,
    width: 350,
    layout: 'anchor',
    defaults: {
        anchor: '100%'
    },
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'User Name',
        name: 'loginusername',
        id: 'getUserName',
        allowBlank: false
    },{
        fieldLabel: 'Password',
        inputType: 'password',
        id: 'getPassword',
        name: 'password',
        allowBlank: false
    }],

    // Reset and Submit buttons
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Sign Up',
        handler: function() {
           // location.href = 'signUp.html';
        }
    },{
        text: 'Reset',
        handler: function() {
            this.up('form').getForm().reset();
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Login',
        id:'loginButton',
        formBind: true, //only enabled once the form is valid
        disabled: true,
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

users.json:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "users": [
        {"loginusername": 'user01', "password": 'password01'},
        {"loginusername": 'user02', "password": 'password02'}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Surely your logic is backwards. You want to send the username/password to the server and have it check the value. You do ~not~ want to send all usernames and passwords to the client and then compare them.

Comment: @ Evan, no, we are not working on any server. We just need to compare it in the client side. Is it possible?

Comment: You can do it easily...  but it's really silly...  because it's completely pointless since anyone in your user base could just open the javascript developer tools and see the passwords.

Comment: @Reimius TRUE. But I'm doing a POC on that....may be if someone could tell me how to retrieve the json datas,  it would be really helpful. I just need a code sample on how to retrieve it...

Comment: any solutions? still I'm struggling , not able to refer a json data from my controller :(

Answer (score 0):

> inside init function above this.control
>   try using this..

```
var store = this.getUsersStore();
        store.load({
            callback:function(){
                  var l =  store.first();
                  console.log(l.get("password"));
          }
        });
```

this is how you  can check

```
store.each(function(rec){
        if (rec.get('password') === value) {
            display = rec.get('username');
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As other users have pointed out, it is trivial to perform authorization on the client side of the application. However you have stated that this is not a concern, therefore I will answer your question without addressing the obvious security flaws of this approach.

I see that you're making use of `Ext.getCmp()` therefore your components have been assigned an `id`. This is generally considered to be bad practice as the `id` property is global, and therefore if there are two components instantiated with the same `id`, the application will crash. You may find it useful to instead assign the component an `itemId` and create a reference to easily retrieve the component in the `Controller`'s `refs[]` definition.

For example:

```
Ext.define('nSpace.controller.nSpaceController', {

... other store/model/view here ...

refs: [{
    name: 'userNameField', // makes magic method 'getUserNameField()'
    selector: 'textfield[name=loginusername]',
    xtype: 'textfield'
},{
    name: 'passwordField', // makes magic method 'getPasswordField()'
    selector: 'textfield[name=password]',
    xtype: 'textfield'
}],

this.control({ .. observe events here .. });
});
```

Retrieve a reference to your store, and search for the provided user...

```
var me = this, // controller
    store = Ext.getStore('Users'),
    user  = me.getUserNameField.getValue(),
    pass  = me.getPasswordField().getValue(),
    success;

// Attempt to find a record matching the provided user/pass
success = store.findBy(function(rec){
    return (rec.get('loginusername') === user && rec.get('password') === pass);
});

// Store findBy returns the index, or -1 if no matching record is found
if(success >= 0){
   // user/password matched
}else{
   // no user/password match found
}
```